# Improving Mysql sum query performance

Tags: mysql

So , I have a table like this with around 48 million rows.

```
User    Count
1232    12
12331   4534
...     ...
...     ....
```

This is a read only table. There wont be any more data added to this. I need to find the sum of count column for all the users between two **userid**...

The query I have right now is:

```
Select sum(count) from table where user between x and Y.
```

But this takes like more than 2 seconds for each query. I need to bring it down drastically. Is there any way i could do this?? Do i need to create a clustered index or any other configuration that you can think of ?

UPDATE: I already have an index on user column

Comment: Just an index on `User`. If that doesn't help enough, you might want to precompute sums on chunks of your database.

Comment: >So , I have a table like this with more than a million rows. That's not 2 much and should not bring the performance down like this. Do you have an index on the User-Column? If not, that would increase performance as the database doesn't need to order the table first and then scan for the provided user ids. What does `explain plan for Select sum(count) from table where user between x and Y` say about how the database is handling your request?

Comment: Its actually 48 million. sorry for the wrong info

Comment: +----+-------------+-------+-------+---------------+---------+---------+------+--------+-------------+
| id | select_type | table | type  | possible_keys | key     | key_len | ref  | rows   | Extra       |
+----+-------------+-------+-------+---------------+---------+---------+------+--------+-------------+
|  1 | SIMPLE      | q6    | range | userind       | userind | 9       | NULL | 534548 | Using where |
+----+-------------+-------+-------+---------------+---------+---------+------+--------+-------------+

Comment: Why don't partition your table with `user`.

Answer (score 1):

If you're getting unsatisfactory performance with an index in place, and your database is read-only, you might consider the method I mentioned in the comments: precompute sums for chunks. It goes one step further than partitioning: partitioning would be able to calculate your sum in parallel, but precalculated sums beat it by a large margin. The ideal chunk size is somewhere around the square root of the number of rows in your table.

Say that this is your table:

```
CREATE TABLE foo (
  user INTEGER AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
  cnt INTEGER
);

INSERT INTO foo (cnt) VALUES (1), (4), (9), (16), (25), (36), (49), (64), (81), (100);
```

Now make a precomputed chunk-sum table. I'm using SQL variables here for clarity, you would probably not need to use those, as you will construct your query from another programming language:

```
SET @block = 3;

CREATE TABLE foosums (
  block INTEGER PRIMARY KEY,
  cntsum INTEGER
)
SELECT FLOOR((user - 1) / @block) AS block, SUM(cnt) AS cntsum
FROM foo GROUP BY block;
```

Now, to calculate sum between `@from` and `@to`, you would grab the sum of all the full chunks between those two, and add all the individual rows that were before the chunks and after the chunks. In this example, to add rows 1..10, we'll take chunk 1...3, chunk 4..6, chunk 7..9, and an individual row 10.

```
SET @from=1, @to=10;

SELECT
  COALESCE((
    SELECT SUM(cnt)
    FROM foo
    WHERE user >= @from AND user < CEILING((@from - 1) / @block) * @block + 1
  ), 0)
+ COALESCE((
    SELECT SUM(cntsum)
    FROM foosums
    WHERE block >= CEILING((@from - 1) / @block) AND block < FLOOR(@to / @block)
  ), 0)
+ COALESCE((
    SELECT SUM(cnt)
    FROM foo
    WHERE user > FLOOR(@to / @block) * @block AND user <= @to
  ), 0)
AS blocked_total;
```

To verify all is working as it should, here is the unoptimised query, not using chunk sums:

```
SELECT SUM(cnt) AS individual_total FROM foo WHERE user >= @from AND user <= @to;
```

And in the end, a visualisation to help you see exactly what data is encompassed by the optimised query:

```
SELECT * FROM foo WHERE user >= @from AND user < CEILING((@from - 1) / @block) * @block + 1;
SELECT * FROM foosums WHERE block >= CEILING((@from - 1) / @block) AND block < FLOOR(@to / @block);
SELECT * FROM foo WHERE user > FLOOR(@to / @block) * @block AND user <= @to;
```

[SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/bb5408/1)

---

*) "chunk" == "block". I wrote the code before the text, and didn't feel like changing terminology :p

Comment: Actualy ended up implementing the same thing

Answer (score 0):

A little lo-tech of an answer maybe from a self-taught person unfamiliar with some of the more advanced techniques available. Disclaimer complete. Here's what I'd do, if I KNEW the data would NOT ever change.

I'd create a script to split it up into a few dozen or even a hundred separate tables, clustered and named according to the range. For example table one could be named "cluster_1_to_10000" or whatever based on what you know about the ranges and user numbers.

That way when you're querying, you could make the table name dynamic in your code according to the range and save time filtering through gads of irrelevant data. It would make the PHP? more complex, especially if the range fell in between multiple tables, but I think the extra 30 lines or so of PHP code would be worthwhile to skip the few hundred thousand rows each time.

Not sure if this is explained well, I can give some pseudo-code examples if you like.

Edit for Pseudo-Code

Tables named: "table_1_to_499999", "table_500000_to_999999", etc.
You would need to write a script to split these up and create each table, and obviously keep your original, just in case.

Pseudo Code (sorry not familiar with java):

```
Var StartTable="";
Var EndTable="";

var Table=array();

Table=//populate table from select tables statement to get them in order
//make each tables key the start value as it pulls the table list from your database
//for example 
Table[1]="table_1_to_499999"
Table[500000]="table_500000_to_999999", etc.

//now you have your two user id's
user-id1 and user-id2;

var table1='';
var table2='';

var key1=0;
var key2=0;

foreach(Table as key=>val)
{
   if(user_id1>key)
   {
      table1=val;
      key1=key;
   }
}

foreach(Table as key=>val)
{
   if(user_id2>key)
   {
      table2=val;
      key2=key;
   }
}

if(key1==key2)
{
   //do your query here, all from the same table, both id's are in the same table, so you can query either table1 or table2 to get your data
}
else if(key1>key2)
{
   //query all results greater than or equal to user-id1 in table 1
   //query all results less than or equal to user-id2 in table 2
   //add the two results together
}
else if(key1<key2)
{
   //query all results less than or equal to user-id1 in table 1
   //query all results greater than or equal to user-id2 in table 2
   //add the two results together
}
```

I think that about covers it...maybe I'm out to lunch, but I think this would while increasing complexity once, drastically save on queries. You MAY have to do two queries to pull the data, increasing some of your overhead, but you're only querying a million rows tops instead of 48 million. Less depending on how you split them up.

Comment: I kind of get what you are saying. I am not using PHP. I am using java to query the table. A pseudo code would be helpful.

Also, There are 48 million rows, so i dont know what chunks it should be split into

Comment: Maybe 500,000 per table? Even less to optimize. You could use a switch statement to narrow down the tables to query based on the id numbers you're using.

Comment: But wont that kind of require multiple calls to the database?? I also have like 10000rps accessing the database. So, would it be feasible?

Comment: just updated the post to include some sleepy barely legible pseudo code...going to bed now lol but I hope this helps! If not, best of luck...

Comment: This sounds like a clumsy attempt at partitioning

Comment: Strawberry can you elaborate? As I mentioned in my disclaimer this is a self taught method I have used. If there is a better way, I'd love to hear the solution, as I could implement it on my own systems as well.